# Data Adapter fill method is failing and code is skipped

Tags: vb.net, dataset, dataadapter

I am a beginner with visual basic and I'm developing Visual Basic Windows application using Visual Basic 2012. On a form which allows users to add/update Master Customer records, there is a combo box which allows users to search for records by customer number. During the Load event of this form, I am trying to populate that combo box with the customer numbers. When I execute the code below in debug mode, I notice that once the adapter.fill(table) line is executed, there is an error/exception, and the code ends. There is no error message and the code doesn't stop...it simply continues on and loads the rest of the form, but obviously doesn't fill the combo box with data.

```
Private Sub frmMasterEntry_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.CenterToScreen()

    'Initialize the controls on the form
    InitializeForm()

    'Fill the Drop-Down lists on the form
    LoadComboBoxes()

    'Initialize current master
    CurrentMaster.Initialize()

    'Testing binding data to a combo box
    Try
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=" & strServer & ";initial Catalog=" & strDatabase & ";persist security info=True;User ID=" & strUserName & ";Password=" & strPassword)
        connection.Open()
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("select * from AC_Master", connection)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        Dim table As New DataSet()
        adapter.Fill(table)
        cboPolicySearch.DataSource = adapter
        cboPolicySearch.DisplayMember = "MasterRefID"
        cboPolicySearch.ValueMember = "MasterID"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error loading the Policy Search ComboBox")
    End Try

End Sub     'frmMasterEntry_Load
```

Can anyone see what might be causing this adapter.fill line to fail? Any insights would be appreciated. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Here is an update to the original post:
The ex.message is "The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'AC_Master', database 'AccountingCollections', schema 'dbo'."

Comment: What is the error? I'm guessing the code lands in the `Catch ex As Exception` but you are swallowing the error. Put a breakpoint on the `Catch` and examine the error (`ex`).

Comment: If an exception happens in Form Load, it wont be reported - the form will just show.  Move the code to the Shown event so you can see what the exception is.  Also, please read [Ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: Thanks, Bugs. It appears that I have a permissions error on the SELECT. Here is the message: "The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'AC_Master', database 'AccountingCollections', schema 'dbo'."

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the error. Looks like you've got permission problems though which you'll have to look into. Make sure your the user you are passing in the connection string has permissions.

Comment: Thanks, Bugs. Yes, the user and password is the same user I'm using for accessing the database (stored procedures). That code seems to be working, but when I try to use the SQL command instead of a call to the stored procedure, it is not working.